# Use named pipes in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, named-pipe

In my application I want to modify various mp3 and then mix them together. I know I could do it with a single command line in FFmpeg but it can end up very messy since I need to use various filter on each sample and I have five of them. My idea is to edit each sample individually, save them into a pipe and finally mix them.

```
import subprocess
import os

def create_pipes():
    os.mkfifo("pipe1")
    os.mkfifo("pipe2")

    
def create_samp():   
    sample= subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", "https://freesound.org/data/previews/186/186942_2594536-hq.mp3", \
                            "-af", "adelay=15000|15000", "-f", "mp3", "pipe:pipe1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    return(sample)

def create_samp_2():   
    sample= subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", "https://freesound.org/data/previews/370/370934_6399962-lq.ogg", \
                            "-af", "adelay=1000|1000", "-f", "mp3", "pipe:pipe2"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    return(sample)


def record(samp, samp_2):  
    process = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-y", '-f', 'mp3', \
                                "-i", "https://cdns-preview-b.dzcdn.net/stream/c-b0b684fe962f93dc43f1f7ea493683a1-3.mp3", \
                                "-i", "pipe1", \
                                "-i", "pipe2", \
                                "-filter_complex", "amix=inputs=3:duration=longest", "output.mp3"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    process.stdin.write(samp)  
    process.stdin.write(samp_2)
    process.stdin.close()  
    process.wait()

create_pipes()
samp = create_samp()
samp_2 = create_samp_2()
record(samp, samp_2)
```

When I run the script, `create_samp()` and `create_samp2()` are running fine. But as I run `record()`, the program get stuck with no error message so I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Crosspost of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67388548/